# macports mpi4py installation worked but cannot import it "No module named mpi4py"

Tags: python-2.7, macports, mpi4py

I have downloaded py27-mpi4py through macports to my OS X Yosemite 10.10 system. This step seemed to work.
Terminal output:

```
lego:mpi4py-2.0.0 root# port install py27-mpi4py
--->  Computing dependencies for py27-mpi4py
--->  Cleaning py27-mpi4py
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  No broken files found.

locate mpi4py
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/python/py-mpi4py
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/python/py-mpi4py/Portfile
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/python/py-mpi4py/files
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/python/py-mpi4py/files/patch-conf-mpidistutils.py.diff
```

Now when I try to import mpi4py in python, it cannot find it. Does this mean that the installation went well but I forgot to set a python path? Have looked through many posts on the web, but I could not find a guide helping me through this step.

I'm new to mpi and macports. Much appreciated if you have suggestions what I could try.
Best wishes, J.

Comment: `port contents py27-mpi4y` shows you the files installed by this port. Note that MacPorts-installed Python modules will only work with MacPorts' Python, so make sure you are running the Python in `/opt/local/bin` to test the import.

Comment: Your suggestion was right, many thanks.`which python` showed that my path was `/usr/..' and not '/opt/local/bin'. I added (exported) the path to my .bashrc file, typed `source ~/.bashrc' and loaded mpi4py in python without problem. A problem arose after closing python, the shell became unresponsive so I had to update my python27 version with python27-readline. Now everything works.